# Javascript CSS DIV Float

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to create a small algorithm that adds a class attr to a specific element if the mouse reaches the X plain half of the browser or more.

I am also going to provide you with a screenshot where I need to use this kind of application.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ur101d&s=8#.VVsOR0ai2Uk

[image]

As you can see in the image above, if the poster is too far on the right the div that appears on hover stretches out of the browser.

Thats why i need to add that class to move it a bit when the mouse reaches that distance on X.

Here's what i've tried so far but the if condition that I applied does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    function readMouseMove(e) {
        var result_x = document.getElementById('x_result');
        var result_y = document.getElementById('y_result');
        result_x.innerHTML = e.clientX;
        result_y.innerHTML = e.clientY;
        var distance = window.innerWith;
        var math = distance / 2;
        if (e.clientX >= math) {
            result_x.setAttribute('class', 'special');

        }
    }
    document.onmousemove = readMouseMove;
    </script>
    <style>
    .special {
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Document that reads mouse movement</h1>
    <h2 id="x_result">0</h2>
    <h2 id="y_result">0</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just refactored your condition, there was a spelling mistake:

```
if(e.clientX >= window.innerWidth / 2) { 
    result_x.setAttribute('class','special');
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks so much this works fine. Can you please be more specific as in where that mistake was?

Comment: Ok i named my variable distance xD that was causing the problem

Comment: @AndreiPirvu the problem was in your distance variable, cause `window.innerWith` does not exist, it is `window.innerWidth` ;)